# SpringData Repository method returning empty collection

Tags: hibernate, repository, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a repository as follows with a method defined in it:

```
public interface BillPaymentRepository extends JpaRepository<BillPayment, String>{
    Collection<BillPayment> findByBillBillNumber(String billNo);

}
```

Relevant entities are as follows:

```
@Entity
public class BillPayment {

    @Id
    private String transactionNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    private Bill bill;

    private Float amountPaid;

    public String getTransactionNumber() {
        return transactionNumber;
    }

    public Bill getBill() {
        return bill;
    }

    public Float getAmountPaid() {
        return amountPaid;
    }

    public BillPayment(String transactionNumber, Bill bill, Float amountPaid) {
        this.transactionNumber = transactionNumber;
        this.bill = bill;
        this.amountPaid = amountPaid;
    }

    public BillPayment() {
    }

}
```

Another entity:

```
@Entity
public class Bill {

    @Id
    private String billNumber;

    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    private Month billMonth;

    private Float billAmount;

    private Float dataUtilized;

    public String getBillNumber() {
        return billNumber;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public Month getBillMonth() {
        return billMonth;
    }

    public Float getBillAmount() {
        return billAmount;
    }

    public Float getDataUtilized() {
        return dataUtilized;
    }

    public Bill(String billNumber, User user, Month billMonth, Float billAmount, Float dataUtilized) {
        this.billNumber = billNumber;
        this.user = user;
        this.billMonth = billMonth;
        this.billAmount = billAmount;
        this.dataUtilized = dataUtilized;
    }

    public Bill() {
    }

}
```

Below are the data filled in the relevant repositories:

```
Bill bill1 = billRepository.save(new Bill("B1", user1, Month.APRIL, 10F, 10F));
Bill bill2 = billRepository.save(new Bill("B2", user2, Month.APRIL, 60F, 60F));
Bill bill3 = billRepository.save(new Bill("B3", user3, Month.APRIL, 50F, 50F));
Bill bill4 = billRepository.save(new Bill("B4", user4, Month.APRIL, 20F, 20F));
Bill bill5 = billRepository.save(new Bill("B5", user1, Month.MAY, 30F, 30F));
Bill bill6 = billRepository.save(new Bill("B6", user2, Month.MAY, 30F, 30F));
Bill bill7 = billRepository.save(new Bill("B7", user3, Month.MAY, 40F, 40F));
Bill bill8 = billRepository.save(new Bill("B8", user4, Month.MAY, 10F, 10F));
Bill bill9 = billRepository.save(new Bill("B9", user1, Month.JUNE, 10F, 10F));
Bill bill10 = billRepository.save(new Bill("B10", user2, Month.JUNE, 10F, 10F));
Bill bill11 = billRepository.save(new Bill("B11", user3, Month.JUNE, 50F, 60F));
Bill bill12 = billRepository.save(new Bill("B12", user4, Month.JUNE, 20F, 20F));
billRepository.save(new Bill("B13", user1, Month.JULY, 10F, 10F));
billRepository.save(new Bill("B14", user2, Month.JULY, 30F, 30F));
billRepository.save(new Bill("B15", user3, Month.JULY, 15F, 0F));
billRepository.save(new Bill("B16", user4, Month.JULY, 10F, 10F));

billPaymentRepository.save(new BillPayment("T1", bill1, 10F));
billPaymentRepository.save(new BillPayment("T1", bill2, 10F));
billPaymentRepository.save(new BillPayment("T1", bill3, 10F));
billPaymentRepository.save(new BillPayment("T1", bill4, 10F));
billPaymentRepository.save(new BillPayment("T1", bill5, 10F));
billPaymentRepository.save(new BillPayment("T1", bill6, 10F));
billPaymentRepository.save(new BillPayment("T1", bill7, 10F));
billPaymentRepository.save(new BillPayment("T1", bill8, 10F));
billPaymentRepository.save(new BillPayment("T1", bill9, 10F));
billPaymentRepository.save(new BillPayment("T1", bill10, 10F));
billPaymentRepository.save(new BillPayment("T1", bill11, 10F));
billPaymentRepository.save(new BillPayment("T1", bill12, 10F));
```

But when I am calling the method to get the result, its returning empty collection.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/payment-details")
class BillPaymentRestController {
    private final BillPaymentRepository billPaymentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BillPaymentRestController(BillPaymentRepository billPaymentRepository) {
        this.billPaymentRepository = billPaymentRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    Collection<BillPayment> getPaymentDetailsByBillNo(@RequestParam String billNo){

        /*System.out.println(billNo);
        for (BillPayment billPayment : this.billPaymentRepository.findByBillBillNumber(billNo)) {
            System.out.println(billPayment.getTransactionNumber());
        }
        System.out.println(this.billPaymentRepository.findByBillBillNumber(billNo));*/

        return this.billPaymentRepository.findByBillBillNumber(billNo);
    }
}
```

I am using POSTMAN to test the service using a GET request:

```
localhost:8080/payment-details?billNo=B1
```

I have other services having similar such functionalities in the same project which are working fine.
The only difference in them and this one was the relationship between entities.
So I read about OneToMany and ManyToOne realationaships. And as per this tutorial:
https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-manytoone-unidirectional-tutorial/
everything seems to be fine.

Can someone please help me out, what wrong I am doing?

Comment: I think your query `findByBillBillNumber` is not correct. You are trying to access to the BillNumber field inside the Bill object. Have you tried define a BillRepository? And define the query `findByBillNumber` inside this new repository?

Comment: I already am having `BillRepository`, but the method `findByBillBillNumber` was not defined(as it is not needed IMO as I am doing the same thing in other controllers for `UserRepository` and the method definition is not needed in those case, only repository is defined, and its working fine). Still I tried adding the method and no gain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your data. You have different payments with the same id, when you execute your save's methods you are inserting only one payment and then updating it with the rest of bills. So your find method can't get any payment which match with bill 1 because there's only one payment in db whose bill is 12.

Additional to this, bill number is your ID, probably it's better using findByBill as query method and Bill object as parameter.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that. Copied and pasted the data, forgot to update. My bad. Gave unique keys to each row and now its perfect. One thing that just stroked my mind: `save()` is not a typical DB insertion operation, its more of an update. Had it been like insert it must have thrown the error on the second `save()` call because of `Unique Constraint Violation'. Isn't it?

Comment: Save method will persist or merge your given entity depending if it exists or not. You cand find more information about it in [JPA Repository Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) - section 2.2.1